# Microsoft Excel Error: "There was a problem sending the command to the program."

Tags: excel, ms-word

I am getting this error everytime I open MS Excel / Word. I tried unchecking the checkbox "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)" in Advanced options, but still I'm getting this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i just feel like to share what worked for me as this thing really annoyed me for several months.

i researched on several websites/sources and all the solutions i have come across do not work. such solutions include but are not limited to:

1) clearing of the checkbox of that DDE thing.
2) registry edit (too risky for non-savvy PC users like me)
3) unchecking of "run as administrator"

but just recently, i uninstalled a program called Tune Up utilities and then the annoying error was gone. so what i would suggest for others is to check which programs do you think are incompatible with your MS Office. then uninstall that (those) program (s).

hope that helps.

best,

filousophe

Answer (score 0):

Hey,
You need to deactivate all add-ins

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-or-disable-add-ins-in-office-programs-HA010034127.aspx

one of them seems to be having an issue.

Comment: This worked for me. Previously I had to restart to get Excel to open. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by right-clicking the document and choosing `Open With...` and noticed there were two `Microsoft Word` choices. I chose the second choice. And it worked and fixed the issue in the future.

If anyone can explain this in more detail, please do!

(I was using Windows 7 and Microsoft Word 2002.)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today.  An update to the Office Compatibility Pack that was still on a computer caused the default program for .docx and .xlsx files to be the Microsoft Open XML Converter program and make the "Default Programs" in Control Panel think that Excel and Word were actually the Microsoft Open XML Converter program as well.

Uninstalling the Office Compatibility Pack in Programs and Features and then a simple reboot fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"There was a problem sending the command to the program" has appeared on my Windows 7 machine in the first week of September, 2013.  I tried to repair MS Office 2003 from within the Program and Features, but repair and re-installation have failed due to "unspecified error".  Windows application logs showed that the repair has failed due to "protected keys" in the Registry.  Windows Installer was blocked from writing to MS Office keys.  My antivirus and firewall were turned off.  On the Uninstall or Change programs list I noticed September 6, 2013 entry "Microsoft Office 2003 Interoperative Assembly" from Microsoft.  I didn't install this, so I uninstalled that item.  Afterwards, both Excel and Word no longer showed an error, and files are opening normally.

KrysK

Answer (score -1):

Uninstalling the Office Compatibility Pack in Programs and Features and then a simple reboot fixed the issue.

I am running Office 2013 - Win 7. Un-istalling the Compatibility pack for Windows 2007 AND rebooting, took care of my issue. After the reboot the .xlsx extension default is changed form XML converter to EXCEL. If you need the compatibility pack you may be able to just change the "Default Program" through Control Panel associated with the xlsx extension.