# MVC3 return File action causes intermittent Excel program error

Tags: excel, file, asp.net-mvc-3, memorystream, npoi

I have a problem that closely relates to this problem [Microsoft Excel Error: "There was a problem sending the command to the program."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063742/microsoft-excel-error-there-was-a-problem-sending-the-command-to-the-program) whereby opening Excel gives `There was an error sending a command to the program` error.

However, rather than the file existing and being opened or shortcutted-to, **I am using MVC3**  with an action that generates a bunch of data, **generates an excel file** (using [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)), writes it to a MemoryStream and then chucks that to the browser using the built-in `return File(etc)` ActionResult, with something akin (but shortened here to aid readability) to this:

```
return File(myMemoryStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "filename.xls");
```

The first time you click the link which fires this action and returns this File - it comes up with the error. if you press ok and try it again it works, and will continue to work... forever

Now I know this is potentially something to do with **disabling DDE/plug-ins** or something in Excel - but since I'm generating an excel workbook and dumping it to a memory stream rather than opening something that exists permanently on the file system, **I'm not sure** what options I have to remove the issue.

Any suggestions on how to get around it? Perhaps I have the wrong mime-type?

Comment: I too have this problem...any solutions?

Comment: For Info: I've switched to EPPlus for creating the Excel file...it works really well, although seems a little slower.  However, one thing to try is to re-set the Stream position to 0.

Comment: I am resetting the stream position to 0 out of force-of-habit - not sure in this instance if it's actually making much difference. Have found that it's only on specific machines with "new" (2007+) versions of Excel. It may well be the case that NPOI is fully supported only with the 97-2003 format.

Comment: I have same problem. It looks like this is Excel-related, because it happens when I'm downloading spreadsheets from other sites (not necessarily ASP .NET based) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content-Type application/vnd.ms-excel is sending the command to the Browser to open the file in the Browser. Which can be the cause of issue. Try setting the content type to application/x-msexcel.

In your example the browser will try to open an Excel spreadsheet in the browser (if the user has Excel installed).

```
return File(myMemoryStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "filename.xls")
```

> Please make the following change

```
return File(myMemoryStream, "application/x-ms-excel", "filename.xls")
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative - I will try it out.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as the most-likely workaround, in the absence of any other responses :)